# Use Public variables inside the class

Tags: php, oop

```
include('database.class.php');
    $DBobj=new Database();
    $DBobj->cunstruct();
    $DBobj->DBconnection();
    if(!($DBobj->conn))
    {
        echo "DataBase Not Connected";
    }
    $DBobj->DBselect();
    $sid=1;
    //$rtrvdata=new Database();
    $row=$DBobj->selectData('*','users','id',$sid);        
    $first_name=$row[1];
    $last_name=$row[2];
    $email=$row[3];
    $pwd=$row[4];
```

I want to use `$first_name,$last_name,$email,$pwd` these variables inside the class which extends another class.

```
class GitHubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;
    private $fname;
    public function testGitHubHome()
    {
        $this->fname=$first_name;
         $search = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::XPath('//input[@id="email"]'));
        $search->click();
         // typing into field
        $this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($first_name);
```

I have tried this.But failed as it still throws me this error.

```
"Undefined variable first_name"
```

How can I use the variables inside the class.

Comment: Where all these variable are set, means in which file or it is PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase ? Try setting those variable with this variable

Comment: I am including the database.class.php file and outside the class and then I am calling its methods. They are coming from database.class.php file . I have tested demo Outside the class its working but I wanted to bring and use those variables inside the class. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase it is totally different file.

Comment: Try using those variables global variable

Comment: can you pls show me the demo code, neverthless I will appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Once check answer given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `$first_name,$last_name,$email,$pwd` these variables public inside the class then you can access these variable using object of class

**you can use like this:**

```
$DBobj=new Database();
$DBobj->first_name = 'value';
```